# Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined' (PHP)

Tags: php, json

I have a little problem. When I test my JSON page on codebeautify, I get this error:

`E2 ->Error: Parse error on line 1: Parse error on line ^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'`

However, by manually testing my JSON on codebeautify, I don't have any problems.

Here is my JSON if you want to

> Link (JSON): https://source-dvtme.ino-heberg.ca/

Thank you.

PS: Yesterday everything worked (in the day strangely)

Comment: "_Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site._"

Comment: The link gives - *This site can’t be reached*

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will contact the hosting company to find out more. So, we agree, no problem on the rendering side (the JSON), just that the server takes time or even timeout for sure.

Comment: Can't tell if there is a problem with anything except being unable to reach the server.

Comment: My JSON just in case: `{ "informations": { "version": "1.0.0", "uptime": "99.99", "disk__total": "7,2 To", "disk__libre": "6,57 To" }}`